# How to add Grafana Stack alerts to other graph types?

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana 8.3.0, on-premises.  When I create dashboard panels of type Graph (old), I get an Alerts tab and I can create alerts.  But other graph types don't have that.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I go the Alert Rules page, it says "You are using the legacy Grafana alerting."  However, I don't see any way of creating alerts other than on the Graphs (old) panel Alerts tab.  What does that mean that I am using legacy alerts, and how do I create alerts the "new" way?

Answer (score 0):

You create alerts only via [Graphs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/old-alerting/create-alerts/), that's how all my alerts are built or you can use Prometheus Alertmanager(it's more flexible), so you are doing nothing wrong. I am not sure how it works on-premise for the configuration of legacy alerts as I am using Grafana on EKS. Can you please check the documentation for migrating from legacy alerts, it is possible that you need to disable the legacy alerts and enable the new ones: [Link to documentation.](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/unified-alerting/opt-in/)

Comment: No, that’s not my question. The only graph type that shows an alerts tab is the Graph (Old). All the other graph types dont have an alert tab. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The time series for example should have that as an option. It probably comes from the "You are using the legacy Grafana alerting." issue. Try to disable the legacy Alerting as mentioned above.